# Jquery conditional not filtering answers

Tags: jquery, filter, conditional-statements

I'm building a calorie calculator which has a gluten filter. I have lots of elements, and for some filters I wish to use all the items that do not contain a certain class.

But with a lot of items it's sometimes better to reverse the logic and I would like to add the gluten class to gluten containing items (there are only 2 of them).

However, my logic seems not to work.

$ The code for filtering for gluten is found near the bottom.

```
// Dropdown menu icon animation up/down toggle.

$('.dropbtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#myDropdown').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-sort-up fa-sort-down')
});


// Dropdown menu up/down toggle. Javítsd ki)


// $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
//     //if you are clicking on the a tags inside #myDropdown stop 
//     //propagation of the event up the DOM (prevent it from getting to 'document')
//     if ($(e.target).is('#myDropdown a')) {
//         e.stopPropagation();
//     } else {
//         $("#myDropdown").slideUp();
//         $('.dropbtn i').addClass('fa-sort-up').removeClass('fa-sort-down')
//     }
// });


// Hide content

$(".maindish, .soups, .desserts, .teas").hide();

// Hover animation ITT FOLYTASD

$("#maindish, #soups, #desserts, #teas").hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
});



//Main dish

$("#maindish").click(function() {
    var visibility = $("#maindish").is(":visible");
    if (visibility) {
        console.log("not visible");
    } else {
        console.log("visible");
    }
    //$(".soup, .desserts, .teas").hide();
    $(".maindish").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#maindish").toggleClass("visible");

    $(".soups, .desserts, .teas").slideUp();
    $("#soups, #desserts, #teas").removeClass("visible");

});

//soup

$("#soups").click(function() {
    var visibility = $("#soups").is(":visible");
    if (visibility) {
        console.log("not visible");
    } else {
        console.log("visible");
    }
    $(".maindish, .desserts, .teas").slideUp();
    $(".soups").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#soups").toggleClass("visible");
    $("#maindish, #desserts, #teas").removeClass("visible");
});

//teas

$("#teas").click(function() {
    var visibility = $("#teas").is(":visible");
    if (visibility) {
        console.log("not visible");
    } else {
        console.log("visible");
    }
    $(".maindish, .desserts, .soups").slideUp();
    $(".teas").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#teas").toggleClass("visible");
    $("#maindish, #desserts, #soups").removeClass("visible");
});

//desszerts

$("#desserts").click(function() {
    var visibility = $("#desserts").is(":visible");
    if (visibility) {
        console.log("not visible");
    } else {
        console.log("visible");
    }
    $(".maindish, .teas, .soups").slideUp();
    $(".desserts").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#desserts").toggleClass("visible");
    $("#maindish, #teas, #soups").removeClass("visible");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ingredient i").click(function() {
        var calories = $(this).parent().data("calories");
        var carbs = $(this).parent().data("carbs");
        var fat = $(this).parent().data("fat");
        var proteins = $(this).parent().data("proteins");
        var totalNum = $("#total");
        var totalCarbs = $("#totalCarbs");
        var totalFats = $("#totalFats");
        var totalProteins = $("#totalProteins");
        var currentCalories = +totalNum.html();
        var currentCarbs = +totalCarbs.html();
        var currentFats = +totalFats.html();
        var currentProteins = +totalProteins.html();
        var pressed = $(this).hasClass("clicked");
        if (isNaN(currentCalories)) {
            currentCalories = 0;
        }
        if (pressed) {
            $(this).removeClass("clicked");
            totalNum.text(+(currentCalories - calories).toFixed(1));
            totalCarbs.text(+(currentCarbs - carbs).toFixed(1));
            totalFats.text(+(currentFats - fat).toFixed(1));
            totalProteins.text(+(currentProteins - proteins).toFixed(1));
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("clicked");
            totalNum.text(+(currentCalories + calories).toFixed(1));
            totalCarbs.text(+(currentCarbs + carbs).toFixed(1));
            totalFats.text(+(currentFats + fat).toFixed(1));
            totalProteins.text(+(currentProteins + proteins).toFixed(1));
        }
    });
});

// plus gomb hover effect

$("td i").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-plus');
        $(this).addClass('fa-plus-circle');
    },

    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-plus-circle');
        $(this).addClass('fa-plus');

        if ($(this).hasClass("fa-times-circle")) {
            $(this).removeClass('fa-plus');
        }

    });

// plus gomb click effect

$("td i").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-plus');
    $(this).removeClass('fa-plus-circle');
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-times-circle");
});


// Vegan Filter + Description text setup

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#veganDiet").click(function() {
        var filtered = $(this).hasClass("filtered");


        if (filtered) {
            $(this).removeClass("filtered");
            $(".ingredient:not([vegan])").fadeTo(1000, 1);
            $(".ingredient:not([vegan])").css("pointer-events", "auto");
            $("#dietDescription").css("opacity", "0");


        } else {

            $(this).addClass("filtered");
            $(".ingredient:not([vegan])").fadeTo(1000, 0.5);
            $(".ingredient:not([vegan])").css("pointer-events", "none");
            $("#dietDescription").css("opacity", "1");

        }
    });
});

// Vegetarian Filter + Description text setup

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#vegetarianDietButton").click(function() {
        var filtered = $(this).hasClass("filtered");


        if (filtered) {
            $(this).removeClass("filtered");
            $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").fadeTo(1000, 1);
            $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").css("pointer-events", "auto");
          $("#vegetarianDescription").css("opacity", "0");


        } else {

            $(this).addClass("filtered");
            $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").fadeTo(1000, 0.5);
            $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").css("pointer-events", "none");
          $("#vegetarianDescription").css("opacity", "1");

        }
    });
});


GlutenFree Filter + Description text setup

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#noGlutenButton").click(function() {
        var filtered = $(this).hasClass("filtered");


        if (filtered) {
            $(this).removeClass("filtered");
            $(".ingredient[glutenfree]").fadeTo(1000, 1);
            $(".ingredient[glutenfree]").css("pointer-events", "auto");
          $("#glutenFreeDescription").css("opacity", "0");


        } else {

            $(this).addClass("filtered");
            $(".ingredient[glutenfree]").fadeTo(1000, 0.5);
            $(".ingredient[glutenfree]").css("pointer-events", "none");
          $("#glutenFreeDescription").css("opacity", "1");

        }
    });
});

// LactoseFree Filter + Description text setup

// $(document).ready(function() {
//     $("#vegetarianDietButton").click(function() {
//         var filtered = $(this).hasClass("filtered");


//         if (filtered) {
//             $(this).removeClass("filtered");
//             $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").fadeTo(1000, 1);
//             $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").css("pointer-events", "auto");
//           $("#vegetarianDescription").css("opacity", "0");


//         } else {

//             $(this).addClass("filtered");
//             $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").fadeTo(1000, 0.5);
//             $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").css("pointer-events", "none");
//           $("#vegetarianDescription").css("opacity", "1");

//         }
//     });
// });

// NoAddedSugar Filter + Description text setup

// $(document).ready(function() {
//     $("#vegetarianDietButton").click(function() {
//         var filtered = $(this).hasClass("filtered");


//         if (filtered) {
//             $(this).removeClass("filtered");
//             $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").fadeTo(1000, 1);
//             $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").css("pointer-events", "auto");
//           $("#vegetarianDescription").css("opacity", "0");


//         } else {

//             $(this).addClass("filtered");
//             $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").fadeTo(1000, 0.5);
//             $(".ingredient:not([vegetarian])").css("pointer-events", "none");
//           $("#vegetarianDescription").css("opacity", "1");

//         }
//     });
// });
```

It won't let me paste the whole code here, so here's a link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/Pbalazs89/pen/aYJRbe

Just as an example, whole wheat noodles contain gluten. They should grey out if the diet is selected. This works fine when selecting Vegan diets, but not for Gluten.

Thanks!

Comment: For me the Gluten free and the Vegan both turn grey the Egg noodels

Comment: Yes, right now it is working incorrectly. I have say 25 items, of which only two is gluten free. The logic now is that I add glutenfree to 23 items, and I would like to reverse the statement so that I only add ''gluten'' to two items. It just is not working for some reason and I would like to grow and find out why :D

Comment: I also managed to make your functions a lot simple and combine them into one, I'll post the result

Comment: Thank you, I'm definitely looking to improve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also very hard to track your code because there is a lot of duplicate but I've managed to make you one function for the diets so you don't need to have all the duplicates, for each diet.

Try the code below

In the HTML file

```
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a id="veganDiet" class="dropbtn2 diet-filter-button" data-diet="vegan"> Vegan</a>
    <a id="vegetarianDietButton" class="dropbtn2 diet-filter-button" data-diet="vegeterian"> Vegetarian</a>
    <a id="noGlutenButton" class="dropbtn2 diet-filter-button" data-diet="gluten"> Gluten-Free</a>
    <a id="noLactoseButton" class="dropbtn2 diet-filter-button" data-diet="lactose"> Lactose-Free</a>
    <a id="noAddedSugarButton" class="dropbtn2 diet-filter-button" data-diet="addedSugar"> No Added Sugar</a>
</div>
```

In the javascript file you can replace all the function for the filters with this

```
$(document).on('click', '.diet-filter-button', function () {
     var map = {
        vegan: {
            attr: 'vegan',
            desc: 'dietDescription'
        },
        vegeterian: {
            attr: 'vegeterian',
            desc: 'vegetarianDescription'
        },
        gluten: {
            attr: 'glutenfree',
            desc: 'glutenFreeDrescription'
        },
        lactose: {
            attr: 'lactoseFree',
            desc: 'lactoseFreeDescription'
        },
        addedSugar: {
            attr: 'noAddedSugar',
            desc: 'noAddedSugarDescription'
        }
    },
    diet = $(this).data('diet'),
    filtered = $(this).hasClass("filtered");

    if (filtered) {
        $(this).removeClass("filtered");
        $(".ingredient:not([" + map[diet]['attr'] + "])").fadeTo(1000, 1).css("pointer-events", "auto");
        $("#" + map[diet]['desc']).css("opacity", "0");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("filtered");
        $(".ingredient:not([" + map[diet]['attr'] + "]").fadeTo(1000, 0.5).css("pointer-events", "none");
        $("#" + map[diet]['desc']).css("opacity", "1");
    }
});
```

I've added `diet-filter-button` class on the buttons, next I've added an event lisner on the `document` for all `click` actions on this class. The event triggers a function that takes the `data-diet` attribute from the button as the identifier, next I have a `map` variable based on the attributes and description IDs that you use. Now for all the buttons you have one function that does all the job.

Try changing the HTML and commenting all your functions for filtering and put only this JS code and see if it works

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to do this. I am examining your code and already learning :-). 1 quick question. I created a new pen with your code, and the functions work fine, however the css is messed up (the table is created in the right, the dropdown menu appears in the bottom etc.) You didn't change any classes but added only new ones so I'm unsure as to what can be the cause. Any ideas? @Sabbin

Comment: - EDIT: Nevermind, works perfectly, a div was missing.

Comment: also you have some issues there... Try using a ide for editing, I have gone over the HTML there are some issues 

`width="15%"="2"` this is not good, remove the `="2"` also there are duplicates of `id` `green` `red` you cannot have duplicates ID, you need classes for that

Comment: you may want to use `data-*` params for the fields, not as you have them now `vegan` etc.. try using `data-vegan="1"` or `true/false`